# Key Vault from both an none domained joined pc and an Function App

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

We have an windows form test app, where we develop and test (this is not a domain joined pc). Then we deploy the code to an function app. I would like the app settings to be in a key vault. However it looks like it is the applications default credentials that is authenticated towards the key vault. With the function app that would be fine. However how do I get the values from Key Vault as the pc is not domain joined. Can I have an app secret and an app id from an app registration or what is the best approach to access the key vault with a set of keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows Forms app is what we call a "public client application", which means it runs on a user's device.
Using a secret is not advisable in these kinds of applications as the user could get their hands on it quite easily.

The more secure way would be that you give the users access to the Key Vault, and get the settings from Key Vault on their behalf.
This will mean that there is an authentication pop-up the first time they use the app.
If you then do token caching correctly, the user shouldn't get these login pop-ups all the time, but sometimes it is needed again.
This approach allows you to avoid using secrets in the app.

Comment: Sounds like the right way. Do you have any pointers on how to work with these popups from c#?

Comment: This sample app uses WPF but should otherwise be what you need: https://github.com/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-desktop-msgraph-v2